# Sublime doesn't auto-complete the unity code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sublimetext3

I decided to use sublime text 3 on windows programming on unity. I installed everything correctly, according to this video: https://youtu.be/z7na1MuMDRg. That is, I installed Mono, Omnisharp, unity3d package. The c# code is highlighted and autocomplete, and the unity syntax is also highlighted, BUT not autocomplete. Why? According to the tutorials, everything should work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of installing all of this, try to only install Unity Completions package: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Unity%20Completions

In my case I use the light version, and it works. BUT I prefer to use VisualStudio in any case.

Comment: I've also used VS before and it was pretty good, but my laptop is very old and can't handle it. And yes, I've heard about Unity Completions, but this article (https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Using_Sublime_Text_as_a_script_editor#Code_completions) says it's not the best solution and it's better to use Mono.

Comment: It's true that UnityCompletions have it's own limits, like do not work across dot notation. But if you are okey with that, is easy to handle. Give it a try and if you are not convinced then keep trying another packages. (I feel you about old laptops, maybe instead VisualStudio, use VisualStudio Code? ^^)

Comment: I was just choosing between VS Code and Sublime, and I started with Sublime. If I don't like Sublime, I'll install VS Code, but it's just that Sublime loads so fast... I don't think that vs code will have the same performance

Comment: You're correct, If you are concerned about loading time speed, should be like Sublime>VSCode>VS

Comment: Man, is it normal that unity completion is being installed for half an hour?

Comment: indeed it happens in some pc's, they got in the website attached a description of what it happens, and that's the reason that I usually install the light version (light version is instantly installed).

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I will refer to Sublime Text 3 as “Sublime” during this instructions reading

Prerequisites:

-Have Unity Downloaded and Installed.

-Have created a Unity 3D project which you are willing to allocate to these set of instructions.

-This Unity 3D project should preferably be a test project, so as to not ruin something important.

### Be careful and follow the instructions exactly. You might have problems along the way but hold on as best you can!

1. [Download](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) and Install Sublime Text 3 for OS X/Windows
2. [Download](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-win) the latest version of the Mono Package(Do Not Use Homebrew!), using the official site. The link goes to the windows download, so if you have a 32 bit computer, download from the 32 bit link vice versa.
3. For step 2, If you have a mac, click macOS and download the Visual Studio Channel(I haven’t tried the stable channel and don’t plan to, should work ok).
4. Once you think Mono is completely installed, please check through the command prompt(windows) or terminal(mac) that Mono actually exists locally.
5. To do so, in the Mac/Windows you can type **mono** in the terminal or command prompt to see the file structure, which should be good. If you are more comfortable using the finder or file explorer, use that find mono in your computer.
6. Reminder - to find terminal or command prompt, search with the spotlight feature(mac - cmd+space), or the search for apps feature(windows 10 - bottom right corner)
7. In the Sublime Text editor, press the sequence of keys cmd+shift+p  or ctrl+shift+p to open up the command palette. (You can click the esc key anytime to exit from the palette).
   Type  **Install Package Control** and then press enter (return key on Mac).
8. Quit Sublime and open it again. This will refresh the changes.
9. Open command palette once more and type **Package Control: Install Package**
10. Enter and then type **Unity3D** and press enter.
11. Repeat steps 6 and 7 to install **Omnisharp** and **Unity3D Shader Highlighter and Snippets** and **Tabnine**

(Omnisharp is a tools kit and system that allows for c# error checking and auto completion etc. We need mono for this, which is why we installed it earlier)

(Tabnine is a wonderful Artificial Intelligence based tool that from my knowledge analyzes the code you have written and quickly concludes methods and attributes you can add based on what you have. In this case, it will immediately know that the syntax is C# with Unity based methods. It is awesome that it caters to Sublime, and it is free for what we need!)

12. Once you have completed installing these packages, quit(completely) and refresh Sublime. When you reopen sublime, you should see a blank, untitled file. If not, just create a new file, you will be fine.
13. Click File > Open > Your Unity Project Folder > Open(This is mac based - windows should be self explanatory)
14. You should see all your assets and scripts folders, but will have a blank unedited text file in front of you. Click save as and the name this file as “SLN_PROJECT_NAME".sublime-editor(More in the next sentence). There should ideally be a YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.sln  file in your Unity Project Folder, so please rename the provided “SLN_PROJECT_NAME” as YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.
15. Save the .sublime-project file that you **just** renamed and place it into the *Library* folder of your Unity project
16. Go into the “SLN_PROJECT_NAME".sublime-editor file in Sublime and paste the following text(You NEED to do this for EVERY Unity project you port in Sublime):

    ```
    {
     "folders":
     [
      {
      "follow_symlinks": true,
      "path": "Assets/Scripts",
       "file_exclude_patterns":
       [
        "*.dll",
        "*.meta"
       ]
      }
     ],
     "solution_file": "./ProjName.sln"
    }
    ```
17. Change ProjName part to the **exact** name of the .sln you are working with from the unity folder you are using(similar to when you create that untitled file to write this in).
18. Close Sublime and Quit It. Open up your desired project that you want to use Sublime with in Unity
19. Click Unity > Preferences > External Script Editor > Change the Script editor to the Sublime Text Application(Mac) or the Sublime Text .exe(Windows)
20. In the tab with the Unity Preferences, find External Script Editor Args with a text box to its right. Paste "$(File)":$(Line) inside it.
21. Close Unity and re-open your Unity project in Sublime Text 3. Now at the bottom of the Sublime Text 3 Window, you should (ideally) see something like “Omnisharp Server Starting” or “Omnisharp Project Loaded,” with “Tabnine” written next to it.

A good idea to do is to click in Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific and paste the following text to allow for autocompletion after punctuation symbols.

```
{
    "auto_complete": true,
    "auto_complete_selector": "source - comment",
    "auto_complete_triggers":
    [
        {
            "characters": ".<",
            "selector": "source.cs"
        }
    ],
    "extensions":
    [
        "cs"
    ]
}
```

Now you should be able to get seamless code completion with error detection facilities **without** Omnisharp overriding Unity Specific Methods.

Comment: I'll try it someday, when I need it again. Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad you responded! Based on your concern, the only thing you would need to do is install the tabnine package and remove any “Unity code completion Snippets” packages.